# ev.h C header missing

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, header

a friend of mine gave me a piece of his software and I'm trying to compile it on Ubuntu 11.04.
Now gcc says that `ev.h` is not installed and I thought you could tell me where to get it because I did not find it by myself.

Comment: what is the software? what librairies does it expect?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html)?

If so, you'd need to install the libev-dev [Ubuntu package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/libev-dev/).

Comment: I did `yum install libev-devel` on CentOS but that did not resolve the problem. Had to copy ev.h to the correct place `cp /usr/include/libev/ev.h /usr/include`

Comment: On Fedora `ev.h` is enough. It seems CentOS installs it in a separate directory for some reason. Does it also happen to provide a `.pc` file?